# How can I cherry-pick commits from a different repository with a slightly different file tree structure?

Tags: git

I have a git repo which has files in the structure `/a/b/c/...`

I've since created a new repo which has the structure `/b/c/...` -- I guess you could say it's a subset of the original repo. I copied across the files with their git history (using [this](https://gist.github.com/trongthanh/2779392) guide, for reference) to establish this repo and have been working on it for a few months.

The original repo is still in use with changes having been made to the files in /c/. I'd like to cherry-pick these commits across to the new repo. However I'm not sure how to do this given that all the file paths don't have that first layer any more. Otherwise though, they're all the same.

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this?

(for context, the original repo was an Android app with a Flutter 'add-to-app' module within it, which has now become a standalone app)

Comment: Did you try it ? Git should be able to match the paths correctly.

Comment: @philb Thanks, I've added the original repo as a remote for the newer one, but `cherry-pick` doesn't seem to be matching the paths. When I do it I end up with the modified files being added as new files in the equivalent 'level' as before, like so: /b/b/c/....

Comment: ok, I know it sometimes work so it was worth a try. Maybe then you could try in the new repo: `git show <original commit> | git apply -p 2 --3way`, starting with the oldest commit in the original repo that's not in the new repo.